# Pipeline failing when adding SonarQube to Azure DevOps repository

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I'm trying to add code analysis to my project, but I get this really anoying error and I don't know how to fix this issue. I think my .yaml file and connection to SonarQube are fine. What could be the problem here?

[image]

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi Did you checked out below answer? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is version of your the SonarQube server.

The latest supported version of SonarQube is the 7.9 (LTS). See this similar issue [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/latest-azure-devops-extension-causing-error-parsing-json/34024/3).